# No IPN for PayPal Pro Subscriptions

Tags: paypal

I have integrated Subscriptions using PayPal Pro for a client but we are not getting notifications to the IPN.  I added this variable (NOTIFYURL=$NotifyURL) and IPN was supposed to be hit for both a new Profile Creation plus the renewal, but neither of those are happening, and I'm actually getting emails in my sandbox that renewals are failing, despite having all the required fields in the initial call to create the profile (and we're getting a successful message) - is this something not fully tested and not working in sandbox as is sometimes the case with new things?

Comment: We have done a live test to see if it was sandbox but did not get a notification message on new subscription signup again, now I'm worried it won't happen on renew either.  IPN definitely working as I've run it through the IPN simular (for express checkout, they don't have a sample for subscriptions).

Answer (score 0):

When working with the Recurring Payments API you can't use NOTIFYURL.  Instead, you need set up IPN in the PayPal account profile.

Comment: Thanks but I've always sent the IPN URL through with the code, that way the client can have more than one IPN script set up and does not have to set anything up in his account - why would they change that back with a recent product?

Comment: It's always been that way with recurring payments.  You could still setup multiple IPN listeners.  You'd just have to use the account profile as a catch-all and then build logic into the IPN solution to push data out to other listeners if you need to, or just handle all the IPN's directly within that single script.

Comment: Thanks - it turns out this is Payflow Pro - which is now called the new PayPal Pro?  Tell me they didn't really rename it, that will confuse my clients even more and now when they come to me to integrate PayPal Pro I'm going to have to ask with one, the new one or the old one, and I know they'll say 'what?'.  But I digress, as it turns out there is no IPN functionality with PayFlow Pro recurring payments so I'm just wondering how they expect us to update our databases with the ongoing payments?  I read someone was using the Inquiry option but that's a bit hit and miss isn't it?

Comment: Oh believe me, I've been griping them about that ever since they first introduced "Payments Pro 2.0".  Really wish they would have called it Payments Elite, or just anything other than Pro.  They're actually calling the Advanced product Pro sometimes, too, so there are really 3 things it could be when you hear "Pro" now.  Drives me nuts.  Anyway, yeah, the PayFlow gateway calls it a "silent post" but it's essentially the same thing as IPN.

Comment: Yes, Payments Elite would have been good!  Ah thank you - I've seen that mentioned a few times and wondered if it was the same as Authorize.net's - will look into it, thanks for your help!